# React native Uploading video from local storage

Tags: react-native

I am using RNfetchblob to upload video from my mobile's storage to api . Here is the code that i have copied from RNFetchblob documentaion .

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload', {
// dropbox upload headers
Authorization : "Bearer access-token...",
'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify({
  path : '/img-from-react-native.png',
  mode : 'add',
  autorename : true,
  mute : false
}),
'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
// Change BASE64 encoded data to a file path with prefix `RNFetchBlob-file://`.
// Or simply wrap the file path with RNFetchBlob.wrap().
}, RNFetchBlob.wrap(PATH_TO_THE_FILE))
.then((res) => {
   console.log(res.text())
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   // error handling ..
 })
```

I am confused with two terms 1.path   2.PATH_TO_THE_FILE
How to find the path of video on my mobile. WHAT is PATH_TO_THE_FILE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the way you tried but I made it like that with formData after picking the image and for video it should work same:

```
 const data = new FormData();
        data.append('photo', {
            uri: this.state.uri,
            type: 'image/jpeg', // or photo.type
            name: 'testPhotoName'
        });

        fetch('https://xx/react_uploadpic', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: data,
        }).then((response) => console.log(response)).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
```